# How to maintain the data types of columns after executing createOrReplaceTempView in pySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe whose data types can be seen below

```
orders.printSchema()
root
 |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- eval_set: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order_number: short (nullable = true)
 |-- order_dow: short (nullable = true)
 |-- order_hour_of_day: short (nullable = true)
 |-- days_since_prior_order: short (nullable = true)
```

But when I register it to a table, the data types all changed to string.

```
orders.createOrReplaceTempView("orders")
spark.sql("describe orders").show()
+--------------------+---------+-------+
|            col_name|data_type|comment|
+--------------------+---------+-------+
|            order_id|   string|       |
|             user_id|   string|       |
|            eval_set|   string|       |
|        order_number|   string|       |
|           order_dow|   string|       |
|   order_hour_of_day|   string|       |
|days_since_prior_...|   string|       |
+--------------------+---------+-------+
```

So how to maintain the original types from dataframe to table in pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

No `createOrReplaceTempView` does not changes the schema. I have tested in the Spark Scala and it preserves the `schema`. It may be issue with the `pyspark`.